# AOZ2261 buck switching regulator doesn't give reasonable output

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck

I am designing a brushed motor driver unit that controlled with a ln STM32F410 microcontroller and a [DRV8243S](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8243-q1.pdf) H-bridge driver. I am using an [AOZ2261NQI-12](https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ2261NQI-12.pdf) to supply the H-bridge driver.

The IC is supplied with 24V.  The polarization is guaranteed by a smart diode and MOSFET.

I couldn't get any reasonable output. The PGOOD pin always gives LO. When I activate the EN pin, the output is at millivolt level.

Something is wrong with the device configuration.

[image: AOZ2261NQI-12 device configuration]

Maybe I damaged while soldering at 310C with heat gun to melt solder (Sn62, Pb36, Ag2.)

Comment: Which solder bridge at MODE pin is shorted?

Comment: SB5, forced to PWM. But also I tried other option. Nothing changed

Comment: Then try with VCC = 5V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IC can't work with VCC = 3.3V because UVLO threshold for rising VCC can be as high as 4.5V. Apply 5V to VCC pin.

The datasheet recommends VCC = 5V which is the voltage that the IC is characterised at.

Also make sure the correct solder bridge is shorted i.e. mode is selected.